# Is it possible to override a dependency injection from a package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm creating a package and want to override the Migrate command but cannot seem to figure out how. It seems like Laravel itself is getting a higher priority over my ServiceProvider, is there a way to gain priority in the override and get my custom class in there via a package?

Comment: When you say the migrate command, do you mean one in particular? migrate:fresh, migrate:refresh, migrate:status?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use a `ServiceProvider`'s `register()` method to bind a custom implementation of `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator` but it didn't work.

Although this is not pretty, I suppose you could use `composer` to autoload your custom implementation of whatever classes you need to override.

For example, let's say you want to override `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator`.

Write a new implementation of this class and save somewhere... for example in `app/Overrides/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php`.

Inside this file, override the vendor class **keeping the vendor namespace**.

```php
// app/Overrides/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php
namespace Illuminate/Database/Migrations;

class Migrator
{
    ....
}
```

Then, in your `composer.json` file, you need to **explicitly** state you want THIS class to be autoloaded instead of laravel's, and also exclude laravel's own class from the autoloading.

```json
"autoload": {
    ...
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php"],
    "files": ["app/Overrides/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php"]
    ...
},
```

And finally, run `composer dumpautoload`. And run it again every time you add a new package with `composer require`.

Comment: It's not the prettiest but I feel like it's better than copying all migrate commands...

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/46843 Apparently it's not considered a bug, just not supported at all.

Comment: I figured it out and added it as an answer, hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I found out why the replace wasn't working, the original service provider is deferred, meaning it's register and boot methods get called just before the MigrateCommand class is needed. When I deferred my service provider the same way it started to work!

```php
class MigrateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->scoped(Migrator::class, function(Application $app) {
            return $app->make('migrator');
        });
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->commands([
                NewMigrateCommand::class
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function provides(): array
    {
        return [NewMigrateCommand::class, Migrator::class];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice find. I didn't know about this at all.

Comment: @IGP Do note that this feature seems to be unsupported by Laravel, I don't see any reason for this to break though, unless they make some major changes to how commands work.